# Android Studio/Gradle works on 2 Macs. Won't work on 3rd one.

Tags: android, git, macos, android-studio, gradle

I've been developing on 2 different Macs with latest Android Studio. I just added a separate Git server for version control, and it appears to work with them.

So I installed Android Studio on a third Mac, and checked out my project from the Git server. The files appear in my local repository, but Gradle reports the following problem and won't let me proceed:

Error:ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext cannot be cast to org.gradle.internal.logging.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

None of the proposed solutions helps. In searching for an answer, I've concluded that the problem may be related to something called `slf4j`, but I have no idea what this is or what to do about it.

Why would everything work fine on 2 machines but not on the third?

Comment: Verify that both `build.gradle` files have been included in the git repository, invoke `Build --> Rebuild` in Android Studio to verify that dependencies have been pulled in correctly. Aside from that verify the same version of dependencies are installed, likewise same version of Android Studio, Android build tools plugin and android gradle plugin are installed across your machines.

Comment: Build -> Rebuild just says "Gradle project sync failed". Cleaning doesn't work either. How could the dependencies be different on the new machine when it got everything from the Git server? Grade shows on the list of installed plugins and the SDK tools tab shows Android SDK Build-Tools. Is it necessary that the SDK platforms installed must match on all machines?

Comment: There was a pretty major update recently to build tools that broke backwards compatibility in places. Note that the dependencies themselves probably shouldn't be checked into git, just the build.gradle files that specify them. To resolve the gradle error try: `Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files`

Comment: Right, I thought that's what you meant about dependencies. Already tried the sync, no joy. Trying trashing my prefs on the new machine.

Comment: OK, trashed prefs, trashed local repositories folder, re-connected to the Git server and tried to check out the project. First saw a message "unable to download module 'app'", then the same old error message appeared. Tried a merge update and the project files all appear to be in my local directory, but AS isn't seeing them, apparently. What the heck?

Comment: OK, closed and reopened the project. Now there's a message "Cannot load module file .../app.iml." because it doesn't exist. I verified that there is no such file in the local folder. What's this about?

Comment: Is the `/gradle` directory included in your project i.e. not ignored?

Comment: Yes, it contains a folder "Wrapper" which contains gradle-wrapper.jar and gradle-wrapper.properties.  Also: I tried the File: Invalidate Caches/Restart. For a minute I thought it fixed things, but noooooooo… Same old problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139049/discussion-between-peter-reid-and-robert-lewis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered that /Library/Java/Extensions contained these 4 .jar files:

1. logback-classic.jar
2. logback-core.jar
3. slf4j-api.jar
4. xuggle-xuggler.jar

I have no idea how these got there or what they do, but when I moved them out of the folder, the problem went away.